# way to go from list of objects to SortedList<string,string> with two of the fields using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have class with 5 fields.

```
public class Test
{
public string name;
public string description;
public int int1;
public int int2;
public int int3;
}
```

In one of my function I have `List<Test> list` which has 10 items. Here I want `SortedList<string,string>` for two properties name & description.

I know, I can achieve this using `for each` but I want to know How can I do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from @HugoRune is quite exhaustive, but because you said you want to use Linq, I'd suggest to add an extension method in your scope to help you with your goal:

```
static class SortedListExtensions
{
    public static SortedList<K, V> ToSortedList<K, V, T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, 
        Func<T, K> keySelector, Func<T, V> valueSelector)
    {
        return new SortedList<K,V>(
            source.ToDictionary(
                cur => keySelector(cur), 
                cur => valueSelector(cur)));
    }
}
```

this way your SortedList creation is composable in Linq computations:

```
var sl = list.ToSortedList(f => f.name, f => f.description);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
var result = list.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ThenBy(x => x.Description);
```

Important:

1. Don't use multiple calls to `OrderBy` as they overwrite each other.
2. The sorted result will be in `result`. The original `list` remains unchanged.

Comment: I have updated my question I want SortedList<string,string> of two of the fields(name, description)

Answer (score 1):

A C# SortedList is a type of dictionary, not actually a list.
If you indeed want a SortedList containing the names as keys and the descriptions as values, you can use this:

```
SortedList slist = new SortedList(list.ToDictionary(t=>t.name, t=>t.description))
```

Be aware that if a name occurs twice this will throw an exception, since dictionary keys have to be unique.

For most practical purposes however, the solution posted by Daniel Hilgarth is what I would use, unless you have a library function that specifically requires a SortedList as parameter.